# Has the sum of 4 cubes problem been proven?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Today in class, my professor was lecturing on the [sum of 3 cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes) and [sum of 4 cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_four_cubes_problem) problems. Namely, can every number be written as the sum of 3 (or 4) cubes? He discussed their origins and showed a few examples, and showed how difficult they could be to find for certain numbers (such as 33 or 42 for the sum of 3 cubes). He said we would not cover their proofs in the course because they were "beyond the scope of the course." When I went to look them up, however, it seems as though they are open problems and have not been proved. I don't think my professor would get this wrong, so I'm a bit confused. I would appreciate any clarification. If they have been proven, where can I see the proofs?

Comment: not proved. Numbers $n \equiv 4,5 \pmod 9$  cannot be the sum of three cubes, as cubes are one of $1,0,-1 \pmod 9.$   The conjecture is that all other numbers are sum of three cubes (note negative cubes allowed with zero and positive).  If true, it would follow that all numbers are four cubes. These are called the "easier" Waring problems as both positive and negative are allowed.

Comment: Right, Demjanenko proved some types of numbers are the sum of four cubes. That is, some things in both 3,4 have been proved, but not easy proofs and not the complete original problems.

Comment: "can every cube be written as the sum of 3 (or 4) cubes?".  Did you mean "can every integer ...."?  If you limit the question to cubes the answer is easily shown to be yes: just take multiples of $1^3=9^3-6^3-8^3$.

Comment: @AdamBailey Yes I did mean to say that! Good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:You can use this identity for finding numbers which are the sum of three cubes:

$$(x-y)^3+(y-z)^3+(z-x)^3=3(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$$

For example:

$(3-5)^3+(5-7)^3+(7-3)^3=3(3-5)(5-7)(7-3)= 48$

Second : we solve this problem to find a number which it's cube is the sum of three cubes:

$$x^3+y^3+z^3=u^3$$

Let $u=-t$ we have:

$$x^3+y^3+z^3+t^3=0\space\space\space\space(1)$$

This equation has infinitely many solutions(positive or negative), as you will see they make a set of particular numbers which means not every cube can be written as the sum of three cubes.

Suppose $a, b, c, d , \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta $ are two groups of four numbers that satisfy equation (1) . Choose $k$ such that numbers $a+k\alpha, b+k\beta, c+k\gamma, d+k\delta$ also satisfy equation (1), or we can have:

$$(a+k\alpha)^3+(b+k\beta)^3+(c+k\gamma)^3+(d+k\delta)^3=0$$

we expand each term; considering groups (a, b, c , d ) and $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta)$ both satisfy the equation i.e.:

$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=0$

$\alpha^3+ \beta^3+ \gamma^3+ \delta^3=0$

We have:

$3a^2k\alpha+3ak^2\alpha^2+3b^2k\beta+3bk^2\beta^2+3c^2k\gamma+\3ck^2\gamma^2+3d^2k\delta+3dk^2\delta^2=0$

Or:

$3k[(a^2\alpha+b^2\beta +c^2\gamma+d^2\delta)+k(a\alpha^2+b\beta^2+c\gamma^2+d\delta^2)]=0$

This relation can be zero if one of it's factors is zero. Equating each factor to zero gives two values for k; one is $k=0$(which is not of our interest because it means we do not add anything to numbers a, b, c and d), second is:

$k=-\frac{a^2\alpha +b^2\beta+c^2\gamma+d^2\delta}{a\alpha^2+b\beta^2+c\gamma^2+d\delta^2}\space\space\space (2)$

If we have two groups of solutions we can find a new group of four numbers as the solution to equation (1).For this we k times of numbers of first group to numbers of second group , provided k is found by relation (2). To do this we need to have a group of solutions, say $(x, y, z, t)=(3, 4, 5, -6). To find second group let:

$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta)=(r, -r, s, -s)$

clearly these numbers satisfy equation (1). Putting these values in (2) we get:

$$k=\frac{7r+11s}{7r^2-s^2}$$

So we have:

$a+k\alpha=\frac{28r^2+11rs-3s^2}{7r^2-s^2}$

$b+k\beta=\frac{21r^2-11rs-4s^2}{7r^2-s^2}$

$c+k\gamma=\frac{35r^2+7rs+6s^2}{7r^2-s^2}$

$d+k\delta=\frac{-42r^2-7rs-5s^2}{7r^2}$

In this way general form of solutions, considerin all numerators are equal, can be:

$x=28r^2+11rs-3s^2$

$y=21r^2-11rs-4s^2$

$z=35r^2+7rs+6s^2$

$t=-42r^2-7rs-5s^2$

For example take $r=s=1$ you get:

$(x, y, z, t)=(1, 6, 8, 9)$

$1^3+6^3+8^3=9^3$